# TypeScript reports error when using certain initial values in Array.reduce

Tags: typescript

When using certain initial values in Array.reduce, TypeScript reports a strange error in this [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D.reduce((p%2C%20c)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09p.bar.push(c)%3B%0D%0A%09return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7Bbar%3A%20%5B%5D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.write(%60foo%3D%24%7BJSON.stringify(foo)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A).

The error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'` is shown for `c` in line 2 of the following example:

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3].reduce((p, c) => {
    p.bar.push(c);
    return p;
}, {bar: []});

document.write(`foo=${JSON.stringify(foo)}`);
```

Comment: The empty array accumulator is automatically typed as `never`.
An alternate approach that should work would be to type accumulator `p` in the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you have `strictNullChecks` enabled and for a good reason. Your initial value for `Array.reduce` is `{bar: []}` which cannot be resolved to a safe type. Is the array `any[]` or `number[]`? Hence, TypeScript assumes it is `never[]` as it cannot infer the type of the array from the usage inside your lambda (it only works the other way round).

By the way, without `strictNullChecks` the array has type `undefined[]`, but the flag basically replaces all occurenced of `undefined` as a type with `never` which causes your example to fail since and assignment of the form `const foo = [];` is of type `never[]` with strict settings.

In order to fix this issue you have to set your initial value to `{bar: [] as number[]}` to explicitly type the array and it works:

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3].reduce((p, c) => {
    p.bar.push(c);
    return p;
}, {bar: [] as number[]});

document.write(`foo=${JSON.stringify(foo)}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I'm still very much confused. Given you explanation it is all about the untyped array but why does `[1, 2, 3].reduce((p, c) => {
    p.push(c);
    return p;
}, []);` then work without error?

Comment: @doberkofler It does not work with `strictNullChecks` enabled either.

Comment: Correct. My mistake. So this case can actually simplified to the following example `const foo = {foo: []}; foo.foo.push(1);` that generates the same error. But why can i then use `const bar = []; bar.push(1);` without error?

Comment: Yet again `bar` is of type `never[]` and it does not compile for me with `strictNullChecks` enabled.

Comment: @doberkofler What the flag does is to replace occurences of the type `undefined` such as your arrays which are `undefined[]`. It replaces all occurences of `undefined` with `never` to cause compile time errors unless you explicitly type them.

Comment: Strange. I just double-checked in the Playgound (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%3B%0D%0Afoo.foo.push(1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Abar.push(1)%3B%0D%0A) and I get no error in `bar.push(1)`

Comment: @doberkofler Make sure to check `strictNullChecks` as it does not carry over and is disabled by default in the playground.

Comment: @doberkofler Then you might have `noImplicitAny` checked as well which will automatically type it as `any[]`.

Comment: Correct! That's it; but then again I used the same settings for foo and bar and they behave differently.